# Convert the Character to Time in R

Tags: r, date, timestamp

I have a charater string `20150501034352`which i want to convert to Date time format using R. The expected output is `2015-05-01 03:43:52`.Any help would be of great help here.

Comment: I really like the lubridate package. Read the documentation of that package and see if you have any questions left. In addition, this quesiton has already been answered before.

Comment: `as.POSIXct("20150501034352", format = "%Y%m%d%H%M%S")`

Comment: @PaulHiemstra will do thanks.@d.b Thia works thanks a lot.